Casting expression result
Would it be possible to cast an expression into a specific datatype without casting the source columns?
Consider the following frame:
df = pl.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]}, schema={'A': pl.UInt8, 'B': pl.UInt8})

┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ u8  ┆ u8  │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   │
│ 2   ┆ 5   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┘

Now using an expression:
df = df.with_columns((pl.col("A") - pl.col("B")).alias("C"))

┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ u8  ┆ u8  ┆ u8  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 253 │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 253 │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 253 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘

This is obviously correct in comp-sci terms but not practical. Can I only resolve this by first casting "A" and "B" to a signed integer or is there a better/more concise way?

Expr.cast()
df.with_columns(
    C = pl.col("A").cast(int) - pl.col("B").cast(int) # int = pl.Int64
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ u8  ┆ u8  ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ -3  │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ -3  │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ -3  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘

There is also a section in the User Guide:

https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/casting/


Yeah, this was the solution I came up with as well. I suppose this is the only way.
